# Splitting column into multi-columns

Tags: r, data.table

For the data given below,

```
data1<-structure(list(var1 = c("2 7", "2 6 7", "2 7", "2 7", "1 7", 
"1 7", "1 5", "1 2 7", "1 5", "1 7", "1 2 3 4 5 6 7", "1 2 4 6"
)), .Names = "var1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))

> data1

            var1
1            2 7
2          2 6 7
3            2 7
4            2 7
5            1 7
6            1 7
7            1 5
8          1 2 7
9            1 5
10           1 7
11 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
12       1 2 4 6
```

I would like it to split into seven columns (7) as follows:

```
    v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6  v7
1   NA  2   NA  NA  NA  NA  7
2   NA  2   NA  NA  NA  6   7
3   NA  2   NA  NA  NA  NA  7
4   NA  2   NA  NA  NA  NA  7
5   1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  7
6   1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  7
7   1   NA  NA  NA  5   NA  NA
8   1   2   NA  NA  NA  NA  7
9   1   NA  NA  NA  5   NA  NA
10  1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  7
11  1   2   3   4   5   6   7
12  1   2   NA  4   NA  6   NA
```

I use the `tstrsplit` from `data.table` package as follows:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data1)[,tstrsplit(var1," ")]



 V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
 1:  2  7 NA NA NA NA NA
 2:  2  6  7 NA NA NA NA
 3:  2  7 NA NA NA NA NA
 4:  2  7 NA NA NA NA NA
 5:  1  7 NA NA NA NA NA
 6:  1  7 NA NA NA NA NA
 7:  1  5 NA NA NA NA NA
 8:  1  2  7 NA NA NA NA
 9:  1  5 NA NA NA NA NA
10:  1  7 NA NA NA NA NA
11:  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
12:  1  2  4  6 NA NA NA
```

This is different than the expected output. I was wondering how can I get the expected output as described above.

Comment: Try `cSplit_e` from my splitstackshape package.

Comment: Does this function account for NA's in column to be splited?. I am getting an error `Error in seq.default(min(vec), max(vec)) : 'from' must be a finite number` when I included NA's, but without NA's, it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `data.table` you may try

```
library(magrittr)
setDT(data1)[, strsplit(var1," "), by = .(rn = seq_len(nrow(data1)))] %>% 
  dcast(., rn ~ V1)
```

> ```
>        rn      1      2      3      4      5      6      7
>  1:     1     NA      2     NA     NA     NA     NA      7
>  2:     2     NA      2     NA     NA     NA      6      7
>  3:     3     NA      2     NA     NA     NA     NA      7
>  4:     4     NA      2     NA     NA     NA     NA      7
>  5:     5      1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      7
>  6:     6      1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      7
>  7:     7      1     NA     NA     NA      5     NA     NA
>  8:     8      1      2     NA     NA     NA     NA      7
>  9:     9      1     NA     NA     NA      5     NA     NA
> 10:    10      1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      7
> 11:    11      1      2      3      4      5      6      7
> 12:    12      1      2     NA      4     NA      6     NA
> ```

To get rid of the `rn` column, we can use

```
setDT(data1)[, strsplit(var1," "), by = .(rn = 1:nrow(data1))][
  , dcast(.SD, rn ~ V1)][, rn := NULL][]
```

#### Explanation

```
setDT(data1)[, strsplit(var1," "), by = .(rn = seq_len(nrow(data1)))]
```

creates a data.table directly in long format

> ```
>     rn V1
>  1:  1  2
>  2:  1  7
>  3:  2  2
>  4:  2  6
>  5:  2  7
>  6:  3  2
>  7:  3  7
>  8:  4  2
>  9:  4  7
> 10:  5  1
> 11:  5  7
> 12:  6  1
> 13:  6  7
> 14:  7  1
> 15:  7  5
> 16:  8  1
> 17:  8  2
> 18:  8  7
> 19:  9  1
> 20:  9  5
> 21: 10  1
> 22: 10  7
> 23: 11  1
> 24: 11  2
> 25: 11  3
> 26: 11  4
> 27: 11  5
> 28: 11  6
> 29: 11  7
> 30: 12  1
> 31: 12  2
> 32: 12  4
> 33: 12  6
>     rn V1
> ```

which is then reshaped to wide format using `dcast()`.

If we would use `tstrsplit()` instead of `strsplit()` we would get a data.table in wide format which needs to be reshaped to long format using `melt()`:

```
setDT(data1)[,tstrsplit(var1," ")][, rn := .I][
  , melt(.SD, id = "rn", na.rm = TRUE)][
    , dcast(.SD, rn ~ paste0("V", value))][
      , rn := NULL][]
```

Answer (score 3):

In `base R`, we can do this by splitting the string by one or more (`\\s+`), create a row/column index ('i1') and assign a NA matrix ('m1') to fill up with the `unlist`ed split values

```
lst <- lapply(strsplit(data1$var1, "\\s+"), as.numeric)
i1 <- cbind(rep(1:nrow(data1), lengths(lst)), unlist(lst))
m1 <- matrix(NA, nrow = max(i1[,1]), ncol = max(i1[,2]))
m1[i1] <- unlist(lst)
as.data.frame(m1)
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
#1  NA  2 NA NA NA NA  7
#2  NA  2 NA NA NA  6  7
#3  NA  2 NA NA NA NA  7
#4  NA  2 NA NA NA NA  7
#5   1 NA NA NA NA NA  7
#6   1 NA NA NA NA NA  7
#7   1 NA NA NA  5 NA NA
#8   1  2 NA NA NA NA  7
#9   1 NA NA NA  5 NA NA
#10  1 NA NA NA NA NA  7
#11  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
#12  1  2 NA  4 NA  6 NA
```