# cSplit_e from splitstackshape package not accounting for NA's?

Tags: r, splitstackshape

I wanted to follow up on the question that I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48326927/spliting-column-into-multi-columns). While I received `baseR` and `data.table` solution, I was trying to implement the same using `cSplit_e` from splitstackshape package as suggested in the comment of my previous post. With the modified data as below (i.e. with NA),

```
data1<-structure(list(reason = c("1", "1", NA, "1", "1", "4 5", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1 2 3 4", "1 2 5", NA, NA)), .Names = "reason", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))

 #loading packages
 library(data.table)
 library(splitstackshape)

cSplit_e(setDT(data1),1," ",mode = "value") # with NA's doesn't work

Error in seq.default(min(vec), max(vec)) : 'from' must be a finite number

data2<-na.omit(setDT(data1),cols="reason") # removing NA's 

cSplit_e(data2,1," ",mode = "value") # without NA's works
     reason reason_1 reason_2 reason_3 reason_4 reason_5
 1:       1        1       NA       NA       NA       NA
 2:       1        1       NA       NA       NA       NA
 3:       1        1       NA       NA       NA       NA
 4:       1        1       NA       NA       NA       NA
 5:     4 5       NA       NA       NA        4        5
 6:       1        1       NA       NA       NA       NA
 7:       1        1       NA       NA       NA       NA
 8:       1        1       NA       NA       NA       NA
 9:       1        1       NA       NA       NA       NA
10:       1        1       NA       NA       NA       NA
11: 1 2 3 4        1        2        3        4       NA
12:   1 2 5        1        2       NA       NA        5
```

So, the question is does `cSplit_e` account for NA's in column to be splited?

Comment: This is a bug. Thanks for pointing it out. It doesn't account for `NA`s in the column to be split. Do you mind filing a bug-report at the GitHub page for the package and I'll look into it?

Comment: The relevant function in "splitstackshape" is `splitstackshape:::numMat()` which takes basically the same approach that akrun has taken in his base R approach. If you try his approach with a column that includes `NA` values, you'll also encounter an error. The function was designed keeping integers in mind, but did not account for `NA` values. Should be fixable using a combination of `na.rm` and `na.omit` in various places.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have filed a bug-report at the GitHub page as per your suggestion.

Comment: As an additional note, data.table solution in the previous post also generates additional NA column for this data set.

Comment: To address that, you might need to do something like `setDT(data1)[, strsplit(reason," "), by = .(rn = factor(seq_len(nrow(data1))))] %>% na.omit(.) %>% dcast(., rn ~ V1, drop = FALSE)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in the bugfix release (v1.4.4) of "splitstackshape". Thanks for reporting it.

After using `update.packages()`, you should be able to do:

```
packageVersion("splitstackshape")
## [1] ‘1.4.4’

cSplit_e(data1, 1, " ", mode = "value")
##     reason reason_1 reason_2 reason_3 reason_4 reason_5
## 1        1        1       NA       NA       NA       NA
## 2        1        1       NA       NA       NA       NA
## 3     <NA>       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
## 4        1        1       NA       NA       NA       NA
## 5        1        1       NA       NA       NA       NA
## 6      4 5       NA       NA       NA        4        5
## 7        1        1       NA       NA       NA       NA
## 8        1        1       NA       NA       NA       NA
## 9        1        1       NA       NA       NA       NA
## 10       1        1       NA       NA       NA       NA
## 11       1        1       NA       NA       NA       NA
## 12 1 2 3 4        1        2        3        4       NA
## 13   1 2 5        1        2       NA       NA        5
## 14    <NA>       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
## 15    <NA>       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

Note that 1.4.4 has moved "data.table" from "depends" to "imports".

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort.